# Country name from ISO short code in dictionary, how to deal with non-ascii chars

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2, country-codes

I'm making a webapp that takes country short code (google app engine get from request header) and I want to get the country name (full name) not just the 2 letter initials.

I tried making a python dictionary but it breaks bkz the names have non-ascii chars (accent marks, etc).. I used the python library "pycountry" but I'm not sure how to include that in my google app engine project. unfortunately pycountries output also has accent marks, so i can't just copy their txt values and make a dictionary...

Besides, I just want the country code to name lookup table, no other details...

Here's a copy of the dictionarys i've been trying to make but they have these annoying accent marks...

Thanks for the help in advance

```
short2long = {"AF":"Afghanistan",
"AX":"Aland Islands",
"AL":"Albania",
"DZ":"Algeria",
"AS":"American Samoa",
"AD":"Andorra",
"AO":"Angola",
"AI":"Anguilla",
"AQ":"Antarctica",
"AG":"Antigua and Barbuda",
"AR":"Argentina",
"AM":"Armenia",
"AW":"Aruba",
"AU":"Australia",
"AT":"Austria",
"AZ":"Azerbaijan",
"BS":"Bahamas",
"BH":"Bahrain",
"BD":"Bangladesh",
"BB":"Barbados",
"BY":"Belarus",
"BE":"Belgium",
"BZ":"Belize",
"BJ":"Benin",
"BM":"Bermuda",
"BT":"Bhutan",
"BO":"Bolivia, Plurinational State of",
"BQ":"Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba",
"BA":"Bosnia and Herzegovina",
"BW":"Botswana",
"BV":"Bouvet Island",
"BR":"Brazil",
"IO":"British Indian Ocean Territory",
"BN":"Brunei Darussalam",
"BG":"Bulgaria",
"BF":"Burkina Faso",
"BI":"Burundi",
"KH":"Cambodia",
"CM":"Cameroon",
"CA":"Canada",
"CV":"Cape Verde",
"KY":"Cayman Islands",
"CF":"Central African Republic",
"TD":"Chad",
"CL":"Chile",
"CN":"China",
"CX":"Christmas Island",
"CC":"Cocos (Keeling) Islands",
"CO":"Colombia",
"KM":"Comoros",
"CG":"Congo",
"CD":"Congo, The Democratic Republic of the",
"CK":"Cook Islands",
"CR":"Costa Rica",
"CI":"Côte d'Ivoire",
"HR":"Croatia",
"CU":"Cuba",
"CW":"Curaçao",
"CY":"Cyprus",
"CZ":"Czech Republic",
"DK":"Denmark",
"DJ":"Djibouti",
"DM":"Dominica",
"DO":"Dominican Republic",
"EC":"Ecuador",
"EG":"Egypt",
"SV":"El Salvador",
"GQ":"Equatorial Guinea",
"ER":"Eritrea",
"EE":"Estonia",
"ET":"Ethiopia",
"FK":"Falkland Islands (Malvinas)",
"FO":"Faroe Islands",
"FJ":"Fiji",
"FI":"Finland",
"FR":"France",
"GF":"French Guiana",
"PF":"French Polynesia",
"TF":"French Southern Territories",
"GA":"Gabon",
"GM":"Gambia",
"GE":"Georgia",
"DE":"Germany",
"GH":"Ghana",
"GI":"Gibraltar",
"GR":"Greece",
"GL":"Greenland",
"GD":"Grenada",
"GP":"Guadeloupe",
"GU":"Guam",
"GT":"Guatemala",
"GG":"Guernsey",
"GN":"Guinea",
"GW":"Guinea-Bissau",
"GY":"Guyana",
"HT":"Haiti",
"HM":"Heard Island and McDonald Islands",
"VA":"Holy See (Vatican City State)",
"HN":"Honduras",
"HK":"Hong Kong",
"HU":"Hungary",
"IS":"Iceland",
"IN":"India",
"ID":"Indonesia",
"IR":"Iran, Islamic Republic of",
"IQ":"Iraq",
"IE":"Ireland",
"IM":"Isle of Man",
"IL":"Israel",
"IT":"Italy",
"JM":"Jamaica",
"JP":"Japan",
"JE":"Jersey",
"JO":"Jordan",
"KZ":"Kazakhstan",
"KE":"Kenya",
"KI":"Kiribati",
"KP":"Korea, Democratic People's Republic of",
"KR":"Korea, Republic of",
"KW":"Kuwait",
"KG":"Kyrgyzstan",
"LA":"Lao People's Democratic Republic",
"LV":"Latvia",
"LB":"Lebanon",
"LS":"Lesotho",
"LR":"Liberia",
"LY":"Libya",
"LI":"Liechtenstein",
"LT":"Lithuania",
"LU":"Luxembourg",
"MO":"Macao",
"MK":"Macedonia, Republic of",
"MG":"Madagascar",
"MW":"Malawi",
"MY":"Malaysia",
"MV":"Maldives",
"ML":"Mali",
"MT":"Malta",
"MH":"Marshall Islands",
"MQ":"Martinique",
"MR":"Mauritania",
"MU":"Mauritius",
"YT":"Mayotte",
"MX":"Mexico",
"FM":"Micronesia, Federated States of",
"MD":"Moldova, Republic of",
"MC":"Monaco",
"MN":"Mongolia",
"ME":"Montenegro",
"MS":"Montserrat",
"MA":"Morocco",
"MZ":"Mozambique",
"MM":"Myanmar",
"NA":"Namibia",
"NR":"Nauru",
"NP":"Nepal",
"NL":"Netherlands",
"NC":"New Caledonia",
"NZ":"New Zealand",
"NI":"Nicaragua",
"NE":"Niger",
"NG":"Nigeria",
"NU":"Niue",
"NF":"Norfolk Island",
"MP":"Northern Mariana Islands",
"NO":"Norway",
"OM":"Oman",
"PK":"Pakistan",
"PW":"Palau",
"PS":"Palestinian Territory, Occupied",
"PA":"Panama",
"PG":"Papua New Guinea",
"PY":"Paraguay",
"PE":"Peru",
"PH":"Philippines",
"PN":"Pitcairn",
"PL":"Poland",
"PT":"Portugal",
"PR":"Puerto Rico",
"QA":"Qatar",
"RE":"Réunion",
"RO":"Romania",
"RU":"Russian Federation",
"RW":"Rwanda",
"BL":"Saint Barthélemy",
"SH":"Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha",
"KN":"Saint Kitts and Nevis",
"LC":"Saint Lucia",
"MF":"Saint Martin (French part)",
"PM":"Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
"VC":"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",
"WS":"Samoa",
"SM":"San Marino",
"ST":"Sao Tome and Principe",
"SA":"Saudi Arabia",
"SN":"Senegal",
"RS":"Serbia",
"SC":"Seychelles",
"SL":"Sierra Leone",
"SG":"Singapore",
"SX":"Sint Maarten (Dutch part)",
"SK":"Slovakia",
"SI":"Slovenia",
"SB":"Solomon Islands",
"SO":"Somalia",
"ZA":"South Africa",
"GS":"South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands",
"ES":"Spain",
"LK":"Sri Lanka",
"SD":"Sudan",
"SR":"Suriname",
"SS":"South Sudan",
"SJ":"Svalbard and Jan Mayen",
"SZ":"Swaziland",
"SE":"Sweden",
"CH":"Switzerland",
"SY":"Syrian Arab Republic",
"TW":"Taiwan, Province of China",
"TJ":"Tajikistan",
"TZ":"Tanzania, United Republic of",
"TH":"Thailand",
"TL":"Timor-Leste",
"TG":"Togo",
"TK":"Tokelau",
"TO":"Tonga",
"TT":"Trinidad and Tobago",
"TN":"Tunisia",
"TR":"Turkey",
"TM":"Turkmenistan",
"TC":"Turks and Caicos Islands",
"TV":"Tuvalu",
"UG":"Uganda",
"UA":"Ukraine",
"AE":"United Arab Emirates",
"GB":"United Kingdom",
"US":"United States",
"UM":"United States Minor Outlying Islands",
"UY":"Uruguay",
"UZ":"Uzbekistan",
"VU":"Vanuatu",
"VE":"Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of",
"VN":"Viet Nam",
"VG":"Virgin Islands, British",
"VI":"Virgin Islands, U.S.",
"WF":"Wallis and Futuna",
"EH":"Western Sahara",
"YE":"Yemen",
"ZM":"Zambia",
"ZW":"Zimbabwe"}
```

I tried to use this code to build the dictionary

```
import pycountry

t = list(pycountry.countries)

for country in t:
    print '"' + country.alpha2 + '":"' + country.name + '",'
```

Comment: Just to check, you know that your code isn't actually building the dictionary, right? It's printing the codes. Most problems with special characters are related to printing them out, but as long as you're just working with them internally, they're usually fine.

Comment: I'm just generating the source code for the dictionary eventually i put it in brackets and set it equal to a variable, i'm not that much of a noob :p

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think you were, but it seemed odd that you would be printing out the contents of a dictionary you were trying to create. Why not just use `d = {counter.alpha2, country.name for counter in pycountry.countries}` (or the equivalent) instead of printing out the source code?

Comment: If someone's looking for library based approach to country code look up then you can use the `pytz` library: http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#country-information

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python source files default to the ASCII character encoding.  If you want to include characters outside of this range in your source code, then you will need to declare the file's character encoding as described in [PEP 0263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).  For example, adding the following line to the top of the file might do what you want (assuming the file is encoded in UTF-8):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

This should cause the string objects to contain UTF-8 encoded versions of the country names.  If you were using unicode string literals instead, then the non-ASCII characters would be decoded correctly too.

Answer (score 7):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pycountry
cc={}
t = list(pycountry.countries)

for country in t:
    cc[country.alpha2]=country.name

print cc
```

`cc` will be the dictionary you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If your input charset is limited to ASCII, you can still get the accents you need by using escape sequences. Try this:

```
import pycountry
import pprint
pprint.pprint ({country.alpha2 : country.name for country in pycountry.countries})
```

This produces lines like this one:

```
 u'CI': u"C\xf4te d'Ivoire",
```